# Set of all continous functions with special Lipschitz property is compact subset

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, compactness, lipschitz-functions

Let $L>0, F \subset C(K)$ be the set of all continous functions f with $Lip(f) \le L$ where $(K,d)$ is a compact metric space.
$$Lip(f):=sup \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}+sup|f(x)|, x \neq y, x,y \in K$$

I need to show that F is a compact subset of C(K).
Per definition, this means that F has to be written as the union of finite open subcovers, right? But how could I go on from here?

Comment: Apply Arzela-Ascoli Theorem.

Comment: Does this mean I need to show that F is totally bounded (which means bounded and equicontinous) and F is complete so that F is compact?

Comment: Prove that it is sequentially compact.  A metric space is sequentially compact iff it is  compact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok thanks, but I have no idea where to start proving this? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Take a generic sequence in $F$ and construct a convergent subsequence